# Form value API Request - JavaScript Axios - Ajax

Tags: api, formulário, request

estou tentando informar um valor no formulário e se o valor for igual ao string do login da api me retornar a propriedade login e mostrar no HTML.

```
Html do form e do button 
<input id="procurar" type="text" name="user">
<button type="submit" onclick="botao()"> Procurar </button>
```

Ao incluir onclick="proc()" no button do html me retorna esse error

ERROR: index.html:51 Uncaught ReferenceError: proc is not defined
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick (index.html:51)

```
// PROMISE - PARAMETROS;
    var MyPromise = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve,reject){

            // Rquesição;
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Consumindo API;
            xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users/diczr');
            xhr.send(null);

            // Status do retorno da api;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        // Passando string para javascript Object;
                        resolve (JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                    } else {
                        reject('Error request;') }}}} );
    } 

    // Chamando Promise;
        MyPromise()
            // Resposta da api;
            .then(function proc (response) {
                console.log(response);
                searchz = document.getElementById("procurar").value;
                if( searchz == response.login) {
                    document.getElementById("loginz").innerHTML = searchz;
                }
            })
                // Tratando erros;
            .catch(function(error){
                console.log(error);
            })
```

se alguém puder me ajudar. agradeço, Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este erro acontece quando você passa para o método `onclick` uma função que não existe. Coloque todo seu código dentro de uma função.

```
<input id="procurar" type="text" name="user">
<button type="submit" onclick="botao()"> Procurar </button>
```

```
function botao() {

    // PROMISE - PARAMETROS;
    var MyPromise = function () {
        return new Promise(function (resolve,reject){

            // Rquesição;
            xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

            // Consumindo API;
            xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users/diczr');
            xhr.send(null);

            // Status do retorno da api;
            xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
                    if (xhr.status == 200) {
                        // Passando string para javascript Object;
                        resolve (JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
                    } else {
                        reject('Error request;') }}}} );
                    } 

    // Chamando Promise;
    MyPromise()
        // Resposta da api;
        .then(function proc (response) {
            console.log(response);
            searchz = document.getElementById("procurar").value;
            if( searchz == response.login) {
                document.getElementById("loginz").innerHTML = searchz;
            }
        })
        // Tratando erros;
        .catch(function(error){
            console.log(error);
        });
}
```

Comment: Obrigado por me ajudar !